# I don't see MS Flow button on SharePoint online

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online, power-automate

I am using SharePoint online version but I don't see any Flow button in neither SP list of Document Library. Does Office 365 global admin need to enable Flow for everyone to use? We have E3 subscription, so it should include Flow in there.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to go to the SharePoint Admin Center, then go to Settings.  In there, you'll find a section titled "Preview Features" and you'll need to enable it there.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Enable-or-disable-preview-features-in-SharePoint-88c69842-7eba-4372-953f-e4cff5818b88?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: Bingo! I found it there couple days ago. It turns out that my organization does not want to use those preview features now. Thanks for your answer